# Suspend spacing between Repeated and number

Tags: formatting

The spacing of the first expression includes extra space before the `5`. I would like to have the same spacing as the second line.

```
HoldForm[4 .. 5]
HoldForm[a .. b]
```

Is there a way to suspend Mathematica's spacing, perhaps with a `StyleBox`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the extra space you see is due to multiplication

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NumberMultiplier -> "\[NegativeThinSpace]"]
```